# Postgresql - Select all tables from a specific user

Tags: postgresql

I have to list all the tables from a specific user.

When I query:

```
select * from pg_user;
```

I get all the users in my database. I want to check which tables one of those specific users can see.

Comment: [This](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30061/how-do-i-list-all-tables-in-all-schemas-owned-by-the-current-user-in-postgresql) may be relevant.

Answer (score 4):

`pg_tables` makes it really simple.

All tables:

```
select * from pg_tables where schemaname !~ '^pg_|^information_schema'
```

Or for a specific user/role:

```
select * from pg_tables where tableowner = 'specificuser'
```

Comment: Thanks Ziggy.
But the thing is that I don't want to know the table owner, I want to know the user, cause in my Database, I have different users for the same table.

Answer (score -1):

user privilege on table:

```
select * from dba_tab_privs where GRANTEE ='username'
```

or

```
select * 
from dba_tab_privs 
where GRANTEE ='put user name' 
and privilege = 'SELECT';
```

Note: In place of username you to have to replace with the user id.

In case of PostgreSQL:

```
select has_table_privilege('postgres','table1','select');
```

Comment: There is no view `dba_tab_privs` in Postgres

Comment: has_table_privilege(user, table, privilege) - I think this function can be used in case of postgreSql